# How to integrate Google tag manager with Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-tag-manager

I want to integrate Google tag manager in Xamarin.

For iOS, there is a documentation on how to do so when consuming [Google analytics SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleanalytics).

However, there is no documentation at all for Android integration.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need any Xamarin documentation for using Tag Manager with Xamarin.
Tag manager comes with Google Play Services, so you just need the Xamarin component for Google Play Services:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices

The documentation for Tag manager is here:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrei suggested, I used in Google play services, although the configuration was not so trivial..

I have created a sample project you can find [here](https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinTagManagerAndroid) to demonstrate how to use Google tag manager in Android.

In short, after you install the SDK, you should call these lines in the your mainActivity class:

```
var tagmanager = TagManagerClass.GetInstance(this);

var pendingResult = _tagmanager.LoadContainerPreferNonDefault("GTM-XXXXXX",
        Resource.Raw.gtm_analytics);

pendingResult.SetResultCallback(new TagMnagerResultCallback(), 2, TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

And after the callback has been called, you can fire your events like this:

```
_tagmanager.DataLayer.PushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.MapOf("screenName", "testScreen"));
```

Comment: But how do we call the events created using the GTM on its site ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about those events? I just needed to push data.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check my [post](http://www.bigmegacode.com/xamarin-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-android/). I explained how to do enhanced ecommerce and if you think could be valuable.

Summary is:

Add Google tag Manager component
Go to Google tag manager web admin, pick android code and go to latest version published. There you should see an option to download a binary file
Name binary as you want and place it inside Raw folder
In Setup or main android class, implement the basic wire up pointing to downloaded Binary in Raw file (This is key)
Create app view event as documentation display, in Tag Manager portal
add basic open screen tracking and watch real time in Google analytics. It takes few minutes to see the data, first time could take up to 24 hours depending on your account
Check my [blog post](http://www.bigmegacode.com/xamarin-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-android/) for further details and let me know if still have questions and I will put together the full implementation.

Cheers